# Java IO exception feature is supported from different Java Version

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I am currently working on a class project with codename one and am running into issues with the built in InputStream and MediaManager classes. It keeps telling me that the feature I am attempting to use is from Java version **1.7.0_06** and to update when I am already using **Java 1.8**.

My error message is as follows:

> java.io.IOException: This fetaure is supported from Java version
>   1.7.0_06, update your Java to enable this feature

My code is:

```
InputStream is = Display.getInstance().
                    getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/"+fileName);
m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "mp3",this);
```

I would post more of the error message/code but Stack overflows "indent" algorithm is messing up when I try to post the full code or error message.

Comment: What version of java are you using to _execute_ the code? Run `java -version` to check.

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error message/full error message/screenshot etc? Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you listed above should work for Java 5 and even before that so it's not the problem.

However you should run under Java 8 which is the minimum supported version for Codename One. Make sure your `build.xml` doesn't contain `1.5` references, if it does replace them all with `1.8`. Also make sure the IDE's JVM is a Java 8 JVM and the language level is set to 8.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using java 8 but your program is still executing on ols version. If you are using maven or ANT specify the version of java to 1.8 and if you are running through console, use below :-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

```
javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8 YourFile.java
```

Comment: My project is using the most current version of Java. Here is a screen shot of the properties of that project: [link](http://imgur.com/a/ntkYz)